Pandas Profiling KeyError: '50%'
Getting a key error using ydata_profiling. Tried versions 4.10, 4.9, 4.8.3

KeyError: '50%'

try:
    from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    !pip install ydata-profiling
    from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

design_report = ProfileReport(df)

design_report.to_notebook_iframe()

There are 99 variables in the dataset. It appears to always stop at variable 50. Is there a hard limit?
When I switch to sampling, I get a different error:
sample = pandas_df.sample(1000)

report = ProfileReport(sample)
report.to_notebook_iframe()


DispatchError: Function <code object pandas_get_series_descriptions at 0x68b9c90, file "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/pandas/summary_pandas.py", line 60>

Traceback:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
last) File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/multimethod/init.py:375,
in multimethod.call(self, *args, **kwargs)
374 try:
--> 375     return func(*args, **kwargs)
376 except TypeError as ex:
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/summary_algorithms.py:73,
in series_hashable..inner(config, series, summary)
72     return config, series, summary
---> 73 return fn(config, series, summary)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/summary_algorithms.py:90,
in series_handle_nulls..inner(config, series, summary)
88     series = series.dropna()
---> 90 return fn(config, series, summary)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/pandas/describe_date_pandas.py:44,
in pandas_describe_date_1d(config, series, summary)
41 else:
42     summary.update(
43         {
---> 44             "min": pd.Timestamp.to_pydatetime(series.min()),
45             "max": pd.Timestamp.to_pydatetime(series.max()),
46         }
47     )
49     summary["range"] = summary["max"] - summary["min"]
TypeError: descriptor 'to_pydatetime' for
'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp' objects doesn't apply to a
'datetime.date' object
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
DispatchError                             Traceback (most recent call
last) File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/multimethod/init.py:375,
in multimethod.call(self, *args, **kwargs)
374 try:
--> 375     return func(*args, **kwargs)
376 except TypeError as ex:
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/pandas/summary_pandas.py:57,
in pandas_describe_1d(config, series, summarizer, typeset)
56 typeset.type_schema[series.name] = vtype
---> 57 return summarizer.summarize(config, series, dtype=vtype)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/summarizer.py:42,
in BaseSummarizer.summarize(self, config, series, dtype)
37 """
38
39 Returns:
40     object:
41 """
---> 42 _, _, summary = self.handle(str(dtype), config, series, {"type": str(dtype)})
43 return summary
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/handler.py:62, in Handler.handle(self, dtype, *args, **kwargs)
61 op = compose(funcs)
---> 62 return op(*args)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/handler.py:21, in compose..func..func2(*x)
20 else:
---> 21     return f(*res)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/handler.py:21, in compose..func..func2(*x)
20 else:
---> 21     return f(*res)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/handler.py:21, in compose..func..func2(*x)
20 else:
---> 21     return f(*res)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/handler.py:17, in compose..func..func2(*x)
16 def func2(*x) -> Any:
---> 17     res = g(*x)
18     if type(res) == bool:
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/multimethod/init.py:377,
in multimethod.call(self, *args, **kwargs)
376 except TypeError as ex:
--> 377     raise DispatchError(f"Function {func.code}") from ex
DispatchError: Function <code object inner at 0x7c3fb52871e0, file
"/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/summary_algorithms.py",
line 67>
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
DispatchError                             Traceback (most recent call
last) File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/multimethod/init.py:375,
in multimethod.call(self, *args, **kwargs)
374 try:
--> 375     return func(*args, **kwargs)
376 except TypeError as ex:
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/pandas/summary_pandas.py:99,
in pandas_get_series_descriptions(config, df, summarizer, typeset,
pbar)
98 with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(pool_size) as executor:
---> 99     for i, (column, description) in enumerate(
100         executor.imap_unordered(multiprocess_1d, args)
101     ):
102         pbar.set_postfix_str(f"Describe variable:{column}")
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py:873,
in IMapIterator.next(self, timeout)
872     return value
--> 873 raise value
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py:125,
in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks,
wrap_exception)
124 try:
--> 125     result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
126 except Exception as e:
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/pandas/summary_pandas.py:79,
in pandas_get_series_descriptions..multiprocess_1d(args)
78 column, series = args
---> 79 return column, describe_1d(config, series, summarizer, typeset)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/multimethod/init.py:377,
in multimethod.call(self, *args, **kwargs)
376 except TypeError as ex:
--> 377     raise DispatchError(f"Function {func.code}") from ex
DispatchError: Function <code object pandas_describe_1d at 0x5a709b0,
file
"/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/pandas/summary_pandas.py",
line 19>
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
DispatchError                             Traceback (most recent call
last) Cell In[14], line 6
3 sample = pandas_df.sample(1000)
5 report = ProfileReport(sample)
----> 6 report.to_notebook_iframe()
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:526,
in ProfileReport.to_notebook_iframe(self)
524 with warnings.catch_warnings():
525     warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
--> 526     display(get_notebook_iframe(self.config, self))
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/report/presentation/flavours/widget/notebook.py:75,
in get_notebook_iframe(config, profile)
73     output = get_notebook_iframe_src(config, profile)
74 elif attribute == IframeAttribute.srcdoc:
---> 75     output = get_notebook_iframe_srcdoc(config, profile)
76 else:
77     raise ValueError(
78         f'Iframe Attribute can be "src" or "srcdoc" (current: {attribute}).'
79     )
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/report/presentation/flavours/widget/notebook.py:29,
in get_notebook_iframe_srcdoc(config, profile)
27 width = config.notebook.iframe.width
28 height = config.notebook.iframe.height
---> 29 src = html.escape(profile.to_html())
31 iframe = f''
33 return HTML(iframe)
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:496,
in ProfileReport.to_html(self)
488 def to_html(self) -> str:
489     """Generate and return complete template as lengthy string
490         for using with frameworks.
491     (...)
494
495     """
--> 496     return self.html
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:292,
in ProfileReport.html(self)
289 @property
290 def html(self) -> str:
291     if self._html is None:
--> 292         self._html = self._render_html()
293     return self._html
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:409,
in ProfileReport._render_html(self)
406 def _render_html(self) -> str:
407     from ydata_profiling.report.presentation.flavours import HTMLReport
--> 409     report = self.report
411     with tqdm(
412         total=1, desc="Render HTML", disable=not self.config.progress_bar
413     ) as pbar:
414         html = HTMLReport(copy.deepcopy(report)).render(
415             nav=self.config.html.navbar_show,
416             offline=self.config.html.use_local_assets,    (...)
424             version=self.description_set.package["ydata_profiling_version"],
425         )
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:286,
in ProfileReport.report(self)
283 @property
284 def report(self) -> Root:
285     if self._report is None:
--> 286         self._report = get_report_structure(self.config, self.description_set)
287     return self._report
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:268,
in ProfileReport.description_set(self)
265 @property
266 def description_set(self) -> BaseDescription:
267     if self._description_set is None:
--> 268         self._description_set = describe_df(
269             self.config,
270             self.df,
271             self.summarizer,
272             self.typeset,
273             self._sample,
274         )
275     return self._description_set
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/describe.py:74,
in describe(config, df, summarizer, typeset, sample)
72 # Variable-specific
73 pbar.total += len(df.columns)
---> 74 series_description = get_series_descriptions(
75     config, df, summarizer, typeset, pbar
76 )
78 pbar.set_postfix_str("Get variable types")
79 pbar.total += 1
File
~/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/multimethod/init.py:377,
in multimethod.call(self, *args, **kwargs)
375     return func(*args, **kwargs)
376 except TypeError as ex:
--> 377     raise DispatchError(f"Function {func.code}") from ex
DispatchError: Function <code object pandas_get_series_descriptions at
0x5a81ae0, file
"/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/model/pandas/summary_pandas.py",
line 60>


Please [edit] your question to provide the full traceback for the errors.

Added traceback

I am unable to replicate the key error. Only the DispatchError

do you have a column named "50%"?

No I do not. It errored at the 50% completion mark
